# change svg:g id to inkscape:label

Tags: svg, inkscape

I made a vector graphic in Inkscape, including layers and sub-layers for further use in Processing. I named all the layers in the UI, and realized that the final SVG only creates an `inkscape:label` attribute with that name, but `id` remains generic:

```
<svg:g id="layer1" inkscape:label="My custom label">
```

I know I can manually edit the labels in the XML editor, but is there a setting somewhere to automatically use the layer name as id?

Comment: That would not be possible in general.  `id` attributes have restrictions on which characters can be used in them.  You couldn't just let people type in anything for the `id` value - without having to encode, in some way, the ilegal characters..

Answer (score 6):

I recently came across this question, as I was looking for the same topic. As it turned out, Inkscape (v0.92) has functions for that purpose now.

You can set **IDs**, and **Labels** in the Inkscape GUI in `Object Properties` menu, and they will be applied to the XML code then.

### Example

#### Inkscape GUI

- Draw a yellow rectangle and select it
- Click on <kbd>Object</kbd> -> <kbd>Object Properties...</kbd>
- In the menu set **ID** to `yellow_rect` and **Label** to `#yellow_rect`
- **Apply changes** by a click on <kbd>Set</kbd>
- To complete this example, repeat the steps above to create `red_rect`, set Label and ID
- Eventually, group both rectanbles and set identifiers for the group as well.

[image]

#### XML Code

When I open the SVG file, Inkscape put my identifiers to the appropriate XML tags.

```xml
    <g
       id="rect_group">
      <rect
         rx="0.11797347"
         y="250.69791"
         x="5.0270834"
         height="18.785416"
         width="30.427082"
         id="yellow_rect1"
         style="fill:#f4ff00;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.52916667;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:3.79999995;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1" />
      <rect
         rx="0.11797347"
         y="258.89999"
         x="24.606249"
         height="16.933332"
         width="33.602081"
         id="red_rect1"
         style="fill:#f40000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.52916664;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:3.79999995;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1" />
    </g>
```

Answer (score 3):

I have the same requirement when I am creating a svg for Fritzing, because fritzing doesn't refer to the inkscape:label. In such circumstance, I can make sure that label holds the legit value for id. So I make a script to do saving myself out of the dirty and heavy job.

Please note that the script **ONLY READ 'Plain SVG'** format.
https://gist.github.com/TerrenceSun/972ef4eea97f331af1e6abfcafb7c6e5

Comment: I am not a programmer as good as I need to be, so I respectfully ask you @terrencesun to update this script so it can work on Inkscape SVG files. I have a file with 82 layers and changing each one of them is error prone. I tried to save my file into plain SVG but all the layer grouping was lost. My final goal is to export each layer into a separate PNG file thru command line.  If you can help me, I'll really appreciate it!

Comment: sorry to be so unfamiliar with perl but I can't see where to set the url for the file here.

Comment: @StaceyReiman The diamond operator can read from stdin or any file specified as command line argument.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know about a setting to automatically use the layer name as id. But why not do it the other way round: if you remove the `inkscape:label` attribute, then the layer name automatically becomes the `id` of the `svg:g` in the inkscape UI.
The attribute `inkscape:groupmode=layer` is enough to make the `svg:g` a layer element.